# Android xml file layout gets messed up when loaded on emulator

Tags: android, button

I am new to Android programming, I have created this xml file: lockerbookpage.xml
that contains many buttons,
however, the error occurs when I load the app onto the emulator, the buttons gets messed up pretty bad

here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/sis" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:text="@string/soe" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/solButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/sol" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/sob" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allSchoolsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sobButton"
     android:text="@string/all" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/allSchoolsButton"
    android:text="@string/small" />

 <Button
       android:id="@+id/mediumButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="35sp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/lv1button"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logoutButton"
       android:text="@string/med" />    

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/largeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lv1button"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/allSizesButton"
    android:text="@string/large" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/allSizesButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lv1button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/all" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/lv1button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="35sp"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/smallButton"
         android:layout_below="@+id/smallButton"
         android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
         android:text="@string/lv1" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/lv2button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="35sp"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lv1button"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lv1button"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mediumButton"
         android:text="@string/lv2" />

 <Button
          android:id="@+id/lv3button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="35sp"
           android:layout_above="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/largeButton"
           android:text="@string/lv3" />

   <Button
          android:id="@+id/allLevelsButton"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lv3button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lv3button"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/all" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lv1button"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
      android:text="@string/ViewNumLockersAvailable" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/unselectAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/searchButton"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
        android:text="@string/unselectAll" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/solButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:text="@string/search" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/unselectAll"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:onClick="returnToMain"
    android:text="@string/logout" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me out
I am eager to learn

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sp` for layout height and width. `sp` is used for font size.

`android:layout_height="35sp" => android:layout_height="35dp"`

Best would be to use `wrap_content` for view height.

Comment: Hi I change the sp to dp, but the layout still gets messed up, I did not sue wrap_content for view height as I wanted to reduce the size of the buttons , please advise

Comment: reduce the height of text instead of reducing button height.

Comment: android tag android:textSize="12sp" in each button view.

Comment: @user2445971 can you post screenshots of the layout getting "messed up", it is probably an issue with different screen dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

['sp' is designed for "font sizes"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), I think the value designation you are looking for in the layout_height is dp.